# Can't create new entity in SQLite with DataMapper

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, sinatra, datamapper

I am new to Ruby world and Sinatra and I am trying to make a database using SQLite3 with Datamapper as ORM. I have installed the gems needed for this action. Here is how I make the db and the model:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :email, String, :required => true
  property :first_name, String
  property :last_name, String
  property :password_hash, String
  property :password_salt, String
end

DataMapper.finalize
```

I have an HTML signup form:

```
<form action="/signup" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="mail" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Register me !</button>
</form>
```

Here is how i handle the signup action:

```
post "/signup" do

  password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:password], password_salt)

  User.create(email: params[:email], first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name], password_hash: password_hash, password_salt: password_salt)

  redirect to '/home'

end
```

When I execute this and after that I log User.all it does not logs the users I have registered.

But if I run irb and type:

[image]

The new user stays in the database.

Any ideas why I can not create users runtime?

P.S. There are no errors logged in the console.

P.S 2. I found that the password_salt and password_hash variables are the problem. Both are strings, when I pass them to the create function it does not work but if I pass for example 'test' to the function it works fine. When I log these 2 variables they seem fine too.

Comment: Maybe you should check if a user is returned from create? (Not sure how datamapper signals failures.) Also - does it work to only create with email?

Comment: If I print the created user of the User.create function in /signup it prints an Object User so I think it is OK. Yes it works with email only because this is the only field required.

Comment: In that case I would guess that the USer hasn't made it to the database yet when you do the logging of User.all. (Connection caching - not flushing writes or something like that.) If you wait a bit and then run User.all in the console?

Comment: There is no new entity written in the db.

Comment: I agree, it's a good idea to put a conditional on the returned user instance anyway, it's a place where errors/failures abound. I'd consider logging the `params` to check they're what you think they are.

Comment: I found that when I pass to the create function the generated password_hash and password_salt it is failing so I think they are the problem. Anyways if I log them they seem fine. Also if i pass for the email for example the password_hash string it seems how it should be.

Comment: Good that you found it! You could - and probably should - add and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like from `property :password_hash, String` and `property :password_salt, String` I get Strings that are longer than the default of the length for String of the `property` method that comes from DataMapper.

Here is the solution:

`property :password_hash, String,   :length => 255`